# CodeCodeigniter cant proceed after login A Database Error Occurred

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

this is my **error**

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET `last_activity` = 1475651663, `user_data` =
>   'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1
>
> UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1475651663, `user_data` =
>   'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"userID\";s:1:\"1\";}' WHERE
>   `session_id` = 'a93b1301e25923d034f0e81140a0be07'
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/CI3/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

this is my **model**

class User Extends CI_Model{

```
function create_user($date){
    $this->db->insert('users',$data);
}

function login($username,$password){
    $where=array(
        'username'=>$username,
        'password'=>$password
        );
    $this->db->select()->from('users')->where($where);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->first_row('array');
}
```

}

this is my **controller**
class Users Extends CI_Controller{

```
function login(){
    $data['error']=0;
    if($_POST){
        $this->load->model('user');
        $username=$this->input->post('username',true);
        $password=$this->input->post('password',true);
        $user=$this->user->login($username,$password);
        if(!$user){
            $data['error']=1;
        } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('userID',$user['userID']);
            redirect(base_url().'posts');
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer'); 
}

function logout(){
    $this->session->sess_desstroy();
    redirect(base_url().'posts'); 
}
```

}

why i cant proceed in posts??

Comment: It seems you missed table name in your update query.

Comment: from('users') <- this is my table?

Comment: I think so. But you need to find the Update query.

Comment: where is the update query in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow code :

```
$where=array(
        'username'=>$username,
        'password'=>$password
);
$query = $this->db->where($where)->get('users');
return $query->row_array();
```

Comment: can you use `$this->load->database();` in your controller?

Comment: my problem is. why can detect the invalid username and password?

Comment: Please print your last query and execute sql in phpmyadmin.
`$this->db->last_query();`